# What solid fuel was used in the Katyushas rocket artillery of WW2?

Tags: rockets, history, solid-fuel, weapon

[The Katyushas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha_rocket_launcher) were invented by the Soviets and used in WW2. They were trucks with rails firing a bunch of small rockets with a range of [3 to 12 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha_rocket_launcher#Rocket_variants).

[image]

These were solid-fuel rockets, but I would like to know **what exact rocket fuel** they used, because it relates to a few of my other questions:

[Why was the V2 not a solid rocket?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/why-was-the-v-2-not-a-solid-rocket-and-or-what-is-the-scientific-history-of-sol)

[What was the first rocket to use solid APCP fuel?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10842/what-was-the-first-large-rocket-to-use-apcp-solid-fuel)

**Edit:** Forgot to post my research. So far the closest thing I found was [this page](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/rt1.html) from Russianspaceweb.com on the RT-1, apparently Russia's first large solid rocket. It says "These engines burned essentially same powder fuel which had propelled the famous 1930s-vintage Katyusha rockets. (177)" and down in the chart it says "Propellant Solid --- RSD-4K". I tried googling that but got nothing.

Comment: That's a real puzzler. I wasn't able to find much information on powder fuels online. And like you said, RSD-4K yielded nothing.

Comment: Russian wiki on БМ-13 (launcher) states that М-13 rockets were propelled by solid Nitrocellulose. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%9C-13

Comment: @Flanker Thanks! I then went to wiki's Nitrocellulose page and it actually has a photo of a Katyusha Rocket, the RS-82. The Russian version of that page says `therefore, OG Filippov and SA Serikovs developed a fundamentally new gun-cotton-TNT powder (TAP) containing 76.5% of gun-cotton, 23% TNT and 0.5% tsentralita.` Not sure what "tsentralita" means, but gun-cotton is nitrocellulose.

Comment: @DrZ214 Found page you mentioned, seems централит is centralite - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralite. Also it says that version developed by Filippov & Serikov (in 20s) used for decade for various development but didn't meet some mass production requirements. So in 30s a group lead by A. Bakaev developed another version (version N) - баллиститный нитроглицериновый порох Н содержавший коллоксилина — 57 %, нитроглицерина — 28 %, динитротолуола — 11 %, централита — 3 %, вазелина — 1 %. As I understood, latter one is used primarily in WW2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [Russian wiki on RS-82](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%A1-82):

RS-82 and RS-132 are unguided air-to-air, air-to-ground rockets developed during 1929-1937. Further developed into М-8, М-13 "Katyusha" rockets.

[image: М-8 rocket]

It seems the final propellant was a **solid fuel N** developed by a group lead by A. Bakaev in mid 30s:

- nitrocellulose (collodion cotton) - 57%
- nitroglycerine - 28%
- dinitrotoluene - 11%
- centralite - 3%
- vaseline - 1%

Production was organized in south of Ukraine.